# What is the name of an anime about a special forces, socially inept high school student bodyguard?

Tags: full-metal-panic

I remember watching an anime about a special ops soldier who is assigned to be the bodyguard of a high school student. He is also socially inept in that he interprets almost anything as a threat to her. I believe it has two seasons, the first season of which is actual plot, and the second season is episodic, comical episodes.

Comment: Sounds like [Full Metal Panic](http://myanimelist.net/anime/71/Full_Metal_Panic!).

Comment: Yup definitely sounds like Full Metal Panic and [Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu](http://myanimelist.net/anime/72/Full_Metal_Panic_Fumoffu)

Comment: Wow... post it in an answer guys, good job. You should have seen how contorted my face was when I read your comments, because just last weekend my friend asked me, "Have you ever seen Full Metal Panic before?" and I said no...

Comment: So I guess I have seen it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To formalize what has been stated in the comments:

The anime series in question is Full Metal Panic, based on the light novel series. Mech-specialist Sgt. Sagara Souske is tasked to protect Kaname Chidori when she is targeted by a terrorist organization. He is a skilled fighter, but fails to react normally in most social situations.

It features 3 seasons (as of 2014):

Full Metal Panic - the first season is very plot driven.

Full Metal Panic? Fummoffu - the second season takes a more comedic approach, with many of the episodes being broken into 2 half-episodes.

Full Metal Panic: The Second Raid - the third season is much like the first, with more of a plot focus (13-episodes).

Comment: I'll give @NaingLinAung a day or two to answer, since he was first.